# How to Align right and fixed

Tags: html, fixed

I need a code to align an image to the right and fix it at the same time, so it's "fixed to the right." i can't seem to find how to do this, as I've searched already. Can someone provide me with one?

I prefer html....

Comment: you can't do it with alone HTML you need some CSS.

Comment: Could someone tell me like where the image is supposed to go in the code?

Answer (score 0):

use css code

```
img {postion:fixed;float:right;}
```

and parent should be `position:relative;`